# How can I programmatically get a workitem "integration build" field value

Tags: tfs-sdk, sdf

I having currently implemented the isubscriber interface so to be able to detect when a workitem has changed. I notice that when a cast the event to a workitemchanged event that there is refernce to: corefields, and changedfields. However, I am unable to get the "integration build" field from workitem as it's based when the workitem is a bug type. How can I get this field value than having to reference the Microsoft.TeamFoundation.WorkItemTracking.Client.dll, and use the function GetService.

cheers

Cyberchick

Answer (score 0):

Get the WorkItem object of your working (from its ID), the use the WorkItem.Item property (see the [doc here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb164821)) with the reference name of the field.

Comment: Hi Nock, thanks for your reply but I was hoping not having to reference the Microsoft.TeamFoundation.WorkItemTracking.Client namespace as illustrated in the doc. I would prefer to be able get it from the server side i.e using Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Framework.Server; using Microsoft.TeamFoundation.WorkItemTracking.Server; As I am using ISubscriber.ProcessEvent() function. I have noticed that when I do: WorkItemChangedEvent Ev = notificationEventArgs as WorkItemChangedEvent; I get the corefields i.e workItemId = Ev.CoreFields.IntegerFields[0].NewValue; but not 'integrated build' field.

Comment: Ok, I didn't understood correctly this part of your post: "How can I get this field value than having to reference". Why you don't want to use this assembly? I did it for a server side project that was triggered by the alert system of TFS and everything was fine.

Comment: Hi Nock, it due to the licensing issues around tfs. However, as we have realised there is no way round this. We have decided not to add this functionality. Thanks for you time in replying